# A set dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am curious about the following problem:

Can we show that the set $\{p(x)\cdot\exp(-x^2/2)\}\subseteq L^2(\mathbb{R})$, where $p(x)$ is any real-domained polynomial function (i.e., functions in the form of the product between a polynomial function and the exponential function $\exp(-x^2/2)$), is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

I am confident in this claim, but fail to prove it. The barrier to me is how to properly use the Stone-Weierstrass theorem (if we need to use it), as it only works on a compact set. Can anyone give me some hint or suggestions? Many thanks!

Comment: Using monotone convergence, you can show that there must exist an interval $I = [-N, N]$ such that $\|f \chi_I\|_2 > \|f\|_2 - \epsilon$. So the failure of $\mathbb{R}$ to be compact shouldn't be a big problem here.

Comment: Yes, along with the above, a high level view: First, approximate a square-integrable function $f$ by a continuous function with compact support $g$. Then, within that support, approximate $e^{x^2/2} g(x)$ by a polynomial.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused with the very last step. The polynomial function can only approximate $g(x)e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$ on $\text{Supp}\,g$, or an even larger closed interval $[-N, N]$, but outside that compact set (or closed interval) the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}\backslash[-N,N]}|f(x)-g(x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}|^2$ is not under our control. Would you please explain this detail a little bit more clear? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @T.Bongers It is a problem in a different way: the tail end of the polynomial you get from the Weierstrass theorem could be large in the $L^2$ norm, even with the Gaussian weight. As the OP pointed out in the comments.

Comment: @user103254 The wiki proof, which employs the entire function and Fourier transformation, is exactly what I want to avoid, since I am not expected to prove the result above by any tool related to complex analysis or Fourier analysis. Actually that is why I post this problem here. Can anyone give me some hint without using those tools? Many thanks!

Comment: @user65018: So what *are* you expected to use?